# LaTeX 3 Command Alternatives

Tags: latex3

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}%[showframe]
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 
\setmainfont{Arial}%{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\logo}{\includegraphics[scale=0.125]{images/logo.pdf}}

\newlength{\logodim}
\newlength{\headerdim}
\settowidth{\logodim}{\logo}
\setlength{\headerdim}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\logodim-\tabcolsep\relax}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}m{\logodim}m{\headerdim}@{}}%
        \logo & %
        \parbox{\headerdim}{%
            {\bfseries University Name}\\%
            Department Name%
        }   %
    \end{tabular}}
    \\[1ex]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em} 
\begin{tabular}{p{0.75\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}<{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{CALCULUS} & \textbf{MATH2301}\\[0.5ex]
    M1 T1: Precalculus & Semster 1\\[0.5ex]
    Maximum Marks: 100 & October, 2020\\[0.5ex]
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What are the new L3 commands for `\newlength`, `\settowidth`, `\setlength` and `\dimexpr`? Can you also point me to the documentation where these can be found?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just ue `tabularx` for the first tabular? With this approach, there is no need to measure the width of the image, nor to calculate the width of the second column.

Comment: @leandriis Indeed. I guess am looking at it from a `tabular` perspective. :) I personally haven't used `tabularx` but you can provide a MWE with it.

Answer (score 8):

Concerning the initial question of the OP.

> What are the new L3 commands for `\newlength`, `\settowidth`, `\setlength`
> and `\dimexpr`? Can you also point me to the documentation where these
> can be found?

Here is the corresponding functions in `expl3` (however, these functions are not meant to be used by the final user but rather by the developper of packages and classes).

- Instead of `\newlength`, you use `\dim_new:N`.
- Instead of `\setlength`, you use `\dim_set:Nn` (or `\dim_gset:Nn` for a global assignment). You don't need `\dimexpr` because you can put a computation in the second argument of `\dim_set:Nn`: `\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { 1 cm + 2 mm }`.
- Instead of `\settowidth`, you use something such as :
  `\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { My text }`
  `\dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }`

These functions are described in the document `interface3.pdf`. Use `texdoc interface3.pdf` in a terminal.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you're doing all those measurements.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}%[showframe]
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 
\setmainfont{Arial}%{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\logo}{\includegraphics[scale=0.125]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} \logo \end{tabular}\enspace
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \bfseries University Name \\
            Department Name
\end{tabular}

\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{CALCULUS} & \textbf{MATH2301}\\[0.5ex]
M1 T1: Precalculus & Semester 1\\[0.5ex]
Maximum Marks: 100 & October, 2020\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Picture with `showframe` added:

[image]

Comment: Interesting use of `tabular*`. I was trying to find a way to ensure the table fits in the `\textwidth`

Comment: @azetina That's what `tabular*` is for: it ensures (provided we use it correctly) that the table fits the given width.

Comment: Amazing. Am currently revising my template that I use and working on a base file to create `.sty` file; thus, the need for the measurements. I will need to create some commands and general settings. Any recommendations? Do you have a well established template maybe from a university? I honestly will need to create `keyval` statemetns for the parameters you see above. For example, University Name, Department Name, etc. Any recommendations? :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two alternatives. The first one uses `tabularx` in combination with the `valign` option from the  `adjustbox` package, the second example only uses a `tabular` to place the two lines of text below each other.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}%[showframe]
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 
\setmainfont{Arial}%{Times New Roman}
\newcommand{\logo}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25,valign=c]{example-image}}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}
{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}%
        \logo & %
            {\bfseries University Name}\newline
            Department Name%
    \end{tabularx}}
    \\[1ex]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em} 
\begin{tabular}{p{0.75\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}<{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{CALCULUS} & \textbf{MATH2301}\\[0.5ex]
    M1 T1: Precalculus & Semster 1\\[0.5ex]
    Maximum Marks: 100 & October, 2020\\[0.5ex]
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip


    \logo \hspace{1em} \begin{tabular}{l} {\bfseries University Name}\\ Department Name \end{tabular}
    \\[1ex]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em} 
\begin{tabular}{p{0.75\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}<{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{CALCULUS} & \textbf{MATH2301}\\[0.5ex]
    M1 T1: Precalculus & Semster 1\\[0.5ex]
    Maximum Marks: 100 & October, 2020\\[0.5ex]
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `X` calculates the difference of the size of the logo with the `linewidth`. Right? This will sure help. Thanks. Any suggestions for the L3 commands?

Comment: @azetina: Yes, the `X` type column's width is calculated to make the overall width of the `tabularx` equal to the specified width (`\textwidth` in case of this specific example) Regarding L3 commands: unfortunately not.